# Text file to the specified datatable column

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to fill datatable from text file.
DataTable looks like:

```
   | Name    |   Number  |
   |---------+-----------|
   |mike     |   1       |
```

Text file:

```
John     1
Alex     3
```

My code:

```
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"qList.txt", enc);
    DataTable txtDataTable = new DataTable();
    txtDataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
    txtDataTable.Columns.Add("Number");

    DataRow dr = txtDataTable.NewRow();
    string[] columns = null;

    for (int j = 1; j < lines.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        columns = lines[j].Split(new char[] { '\t' });
        dr["Name"] = columns.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
        dr["Number"] = columns.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
        txtDataTable.Rows.Add(dr["Name"]);
        txtDataTable.Rows.Add(dr["Number"]);
    }
```

I need to fill like this: names from the file (John, Alex) to column name and numbers from file (1,3) to column number in datatable. My code fill every row in column "Name" of the datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
```

OR

```
txtDataTable.Rows.Add(dr["Name"], dr["Number"]);
```

Comment: txtDataTable.Rows.Add(dr["Name"], dr["Number"]); - helps to me. Tank you.